# Join query with many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to know all ces_status='FINISHED' for tables in a large database where the tables have a created date of today.

This tell me all the tables created today

```
SELECT [name] AS [TableName], [create_date] AS [CreatedDate] 
FROM sys.tables where create_date > '2017-03-08 00:00:00.000'
```

For any one of those tables, I can find how many have a status of finished

```
select COUNT(*) 
from tbl_IADPRDSL1_15_04_05_140 with (nolock) 
WHERE ces_status='FINISHED'
```

Is it possible to combine both of those into a join query to gives me that number in all those tables.  I am a front end developer and I tried query builder and I had no luck.

Comment: Storing data in different tables for each data is probably not the best design.  Are you familiar with table partitions/

Comment: You also might take a peek at this before you continue splattering nolock hints everywhere. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: The table is from a 3rd part application.  This is not a table I designed. 
I want to figure out if I can get the information with one query.  You should assume that just because we have to query a database means we have some control of the design of it.

Answer (score 0):

Two Steps:

1)Run this:

```
SELECT concat('SELECT * FROM ', [name], ' WHERE CES_Status=''FINISHED'' UNION ALL ')
FROM sys.tables where create_date > '2017-03-08 00:00:00.000'
```

Take the results of the above query  and paste replacing  below. Also remove the last UNION ALL statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (<results>)
```

If it has to be done in one step, then it all has to be dynamic SQL and is a bit more challenging.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'SELECT * FROM '.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'WHERE CES_Status='FINISHED' UNION ALL '

Comment: Thanks @RezaRahmati missing a space before the where and should use ' instead of "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one step, you need to enhance xQbert answer as below

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @date datetime
set @date = '2017-02-08 00:00:00.000'

SELECT @sql  = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') + concat(' SELECT Count(*), '''+[name]+''' as TableName FROM [', schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + [name], '] with (nolock) WHERE ces_status=''FINISHED'' ')
FROM sys.tables where create_date > @date

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

it will be only one step.